# how to pass data to next view on button click using collection view in iphone

Tags: iphone, core-data

Right now I am working with coredata and collection. I have an entity in coredta named "Employee" and it has multiple attributes(emp_id,name,address,dept). I am done with saving the data and successfully fetching the data. The thing is that I am using collection view and I am using delegate method("cellForItemAtIndexPath")of collection view and under this I am passing 'Employee'entity data from the coredata. I am setting the title of button by using the employee name(the no of buttons is equal to no of rows in coredata).

The problem starts here right now I want to perform an action on button click in that I want when I click a particular button I want to navigate to another controller and want to display all the information regarding that employee.I dont know how to do this I am pasting my code below.Your replies are mostly welcome:

```
    - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     info = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"empCell";
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView   dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    titlebutton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    [titlebutton addTarget:self action:@selector(onClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [titlebutton setTitle:info.name forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    return cell;
}
```

Here info is the instance of Employee entity. Buttons are displaying fine with their title as the name of employees in coredata. Here in this case I want to pass the id of each employee(say for button1 it is "1"..button2 it is "2") to another controller on button click. The prob is that the id which I m getting is for last button only because on run time the previous emp id is replaced by the last one. And here I am dealing with that particular prob i.e. how to pass each emp id to next controller on button click.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to retrieve the object of the cell of a Core Data populated collection view is as follows. In any case, you **should** be using a `NSFetchedResultsController` for efficiency. Insert your (not recommended) array functions where appropriate.

There is no need for tags. In Interface Builder, just link the button action directly to the view controller containing the collection view. (You can do the connection also in code, by setting target and selector in `cellForItem...` as you do above.)

```
-(IBAction)didPressCellButton:(UIButton*)sender {
   CGPoint point = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.collectionView];
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:point];
   Entity *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   // or: Entity *object = array[indexPath.row];
   // do something with object
}
```

It is preferable to do it this way, because we make no assumptions about the view hierarchy of the cell. It is also a safe way to retrieve the right reference to the cell, index path or fetched results controller object.

The next step is to pass the object on to the next view controller. The standard way is with storyboard segues. You could call the segue manually in the above button handler with

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail"];
```

But in this case, you do not even need a button action. The exact same code can be used in `prepareForSegue:` if you connected the button directly with a segue in Interface Builder to the detail view controller. Make sure your segue has an identifier string (e.g. "showDetail"). Make sure your destination view controller has a property of the same type of the entity you need. Here you can pass any additional data you like.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue*)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
      UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
      CGPoint point = [button convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.collectionView];
      NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:point];
      Entity *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

      MyDetailViewController *controller = segue.destinationController;
      controller.entityProperty = object;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @MUndi for your answer but here in this case i want to pass the id of each employee(say for button1 it is "1"..button2 it is "2") to another controller on buttton click. The prob is that the id which I m getting is for last button only..Becauze on run time the previous emp id is replaced by the last one. And here I am dealing with that particular prob i.e. how to pass each emp id to next controller on button click.